# Way to include non-standard objects in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have non-Ember objects that I want to access from other parts of my Ember CLI app. For instance, I have a facade object that I want to import into one of my components. This object isn't an Ember model or mixin or helper or anything like that, so it wouldn't fit into any of the standard Ember CLI folders. Where should I put it? And how do I import it?

Comment: you could try and add as an asset via brocfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vendor` folder would be good fit, it is imported by default. Otherwise you can make a new directory within `app` folder and call it whatever, then you can import it from within your `Brocfile.js` using `app.import('app/customdir')`.

Comment: That sounds like it'll work, but also like it'll contaminate the global namespace. That is, I won't have to explicitly import them into the files that use them in, such as in `components/my-component.js`. Is there a way to get that level of control over something like this?

Comment: @timothycommoner Do you mean, your custom `facade` files are not part of the es6 module system, but global, and you want them to be part of es6 modules, and not global?

Comment: Exactly. You don't know where I could read more about that, do you?

Comment: Your custom classes are already using globals, if you are concerned, why don't you write them as es6 modules, or maybe there is some shim configuration, I don't know.

Comment: @timothycommoner this discussion seems related. http://esdiscuss.org/topic/module-shimming.